# Left position an absolute div with 100% width with fittext.js

Tags: jquery

I have a headLine div container an `<h1>` and an `<h2>` it is position absolute and has a 100% width, I needed to 100% width to get the fittext.js to work properly, however when I position the div left so many `em`s it gives me a horizontal scrolling bar. I can't do relative positioning due to my structure of my site, I could but it would make things difficult further down the road. Ok So Why am I getting this horizontal width and how do I get rid if it.

View project http://jsfiddle.net/sLXZs/3/

html /js

```
        <div id="headLine">
            <h1 class="fitText">Austin Kitson</h1>
            <h2 class="fitText">Marketing & Sales</h2>
        </div>




                <script>
                    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.fitText').fitText(2.2, { minFontSize: '10px', maxFontSize: '80px' });

});
                </script>
```

css

```
#headLine {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 55%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red; }
```

​

​

Comment: Well, the `left: 55%` property is what's causing the scrollbar to appear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that just fixing the size of the div instead of 100% to be 45% and setting the fittext's `kompressor` parameter to 1 make it work correct.

Css

```
#headLine {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 55%;
  width: 45%;
  background: red; }
```

Script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.fitText').fitText(1, {
        minFontSize: '10px',
        maxFontSize: '80px'
    });
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/sLXZs/4/

Answer (score 1):

Set body overflow to avoid scroll bar:

```
body,html{overflow-x:hidden}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/sLXZs/5/

`overflow-x` not supported in some older browsers. You can try using `overflow:hidden`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep the 100% width style and not use 45% width, it's still possible and can be calculated on the fly:

```
$("#headLine").width(function () {
   return $(this).width() - $(this).css('left');
});
```

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/sLXZs/6/

Comment: I would like to use this but in your js fiddle fittext isnt working.

Comment: @AndersKitson in what way is it not working?  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @AndersKitson sorry I had actually commented the `.fittext` call out: http://jsfiddle.net/sLXZs/7/